# SetText and TimePickerDialog

Tags: android, dialog, datepicker, timepicker, settext

I cannot seem to figure out what to place into the onTimeSet() method in order to setText to the button that it is associated with.

I would like the user to click the button in the layout and it show the TimePickerDialog. Once the user has selected the time they would like to use I would like the time to be set to the same buttons text.

Any ideas?

```
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}

public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user


}

}
```

Comment: did non of the answers worked out for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bit complicated passing data back from a Fragment to the containing Activity.

Basically you have two options, one of which is simple and straigt forward, the other one is more sophisticated but on the long run (and for more complex requirements) would be the better one:

**Simple**

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String timeString = hourOfDay+" "+minute; // <-- just for example, you'll want to do better time-formatting here.
    Button b = (Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourButtonsId);
    b.setText(timeString);
}
```

**Sophisticated**

Use a Listener **interface** in your Fragment and make your Activity implement that interface and set itself as the Listener to your Fragment:

Add this to your Fragment:

```
public interface Listener {
    public void setTime(int hourOfDay, int minute);
}

// hold the listener
private Listener mListener;

// used by Activity to set itself as the listener for the fragment
public void setListener(Listener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

Implement `onTimeSet` in your Fragment like so:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    if (mListener != null) mListener.setTime(hourOfDay, minute);
}
```

Add `implements TimePickerFragment.Listener` to your Activity's class declaration.

Implement the `public void setTime(int hourOfDay, int minute)` method of the Listener in your Activity, e.g. like so:

```
public void setTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    String timeString = hourOfDay+" "+minute; // <-- just for example, you'll want to do better time-formatting here.
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonsId);
    b.setText(timeString);
}
```

Add this to your Activity after instantiating your Fragment:

```
timePickerFragment.setListener(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // button click listener
   button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(button.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
                getTimeDialog(button.getText().toString(), new CustomClickListner() {

                   @Override
                    public void onClick(String value) {
                    btnLogin.setText(value);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                getTimeDialog("", new CustomClickListner() {

                   @Override
                    public void onClick(String value) {
                    btnLogin.setText(value);
                    }
                });
            }
    }
});


     // custom interface time dialog set time listener
     public interface CustomClickListner {
      public void onClick(String value);
    }

     // open time dialog
     public void getTimeDialog(final String strTime, final CustomClickListner target) {

    Calendar date = getTimeFromString(strTime);
    TimePickerDialog timeDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss").format(date);
            target.onClick(dateString);
        }
    }, date.get(Calendar.HOUR), date.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);

    timeDialog.show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just Your using this following steps

```
 private void SetTime() {
        buttonTaskTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String taskTime = buttonTaskTime.getText().toString();
                int mHour = Integer.parseInt(taskTime.split(":")[0]);
                String minutesmeridian = taskTime.split(":")[1];
                int mMinute = Integer.parseInt(minutesmeridian.split(" ")[0]);
                String mMeridian = minutesmeridian.split(" ")[1];
                if (mMeridian.equals(postMeridain)) {
                    if (!(mHour == 12)) {
                        mHour += 12;
                    }

                } else {
                    if (mHour == 12) {
                        mHour += 12;
                    }
                }
                hour = mHour;
                minute = mMinute;
                new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.Theme_CustomDialog,
                        timePicker, hour, minute, false).show();
            }
        });
    }
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePicker = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
            hour = hourOfDay;
            minute = minutes;
            calendarNewTaskTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calendarNewTaskTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
            calendarNewTaskTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            UpdateTime();
        }
    };

private void UpdateTime() {
        String meridian = " ";
        if (hour > 12) {
            hour -= 12;
            meridian = "PM";
        } else if (hour == 0) {
            hour = 12;
            meridian = "AM";
        } else if (hour == 12)
            meridian = "PM";
        else
            meridian = "AM";
        String min = " ";
        if (minute < 10) {
            min = "0" + minute;
        } else
            min = String.valueOf(minute);
        buttonTaskTime.setText(hour + ":" + min + " " + meridian);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes which i always used to

```
custom = new CustomDateTimePicker(this,
        new CustomDateTimePicker.ICustomDateTimeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSet(Dialog dialog, Calendar calendarSelected,
                    Date dateSelected, int year, String monthFullName,
                    String monthShortName, int monthNumber, int date,
                    String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName,
                    int hour24, int hour12, int min, int sec,
                    String AM_PM) {

                ((Button) findViewById(R.id.alerttime))
                        .setText(calendarSelected
                                        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                + "/" + monthNumber + "/" + year + " "+
                                 + hour12 + ":" + min + ":" + "00"
                                + " " + AM_PM);
}
```